# Are there any differences between abort(x) and Responce(status=x) in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

Let's say that something went wrong in a Flask app and I want to return a error code. Are there any difference between

```
if something_is_wrong:
    abort(400)
```

and

```
if something_is_wrong:
    return Response(status=400)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`abort` function comes from `werkzeug` package, (which Flask wraps) which raises an exception, and flask processes it and returns the status code.

https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/1a852423e6fc6d9bd3a0e0c756dde5680c38cee0/src/werkzeug/exceptions.py#L770

```py
def abort(status, *args, **kwargs):
    # ...
    return _aborter(status, *args, **kwargs)
```

here is the `aborter`

- https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/1a852423e6fc6d9bd3a0e0c756dde5680c38cee0/src/werkzeug/exceptions.py#L764

```py
class Aborter(object):
    # ...
    def __call__(self, code, *args, **kwargs):
        if not args and not kwargs and not isinstance(code, integer_types):
            raise HTTPException(response=code)
        if code not in self.mapping:
            raise LookupError("no exception for %r" % code)
        raise self.mapping[code](*args, **kwargs)
```